# Why do I keep getting ReferenceError: * is not defined?

Tags: javascript

New to Javascript and I can't get the error message ReferenceError: calculateOrder is not defined to go away no matter what I try. I've moved my var out and back in tried different statements. Nothing of the knowledge I have so far is working. How can I get rid of this error message? Would appreciate any help or pointers I can get.

```js
var cost = 750;

var pasta_prices = new Array();
pasta_prices["spaghetti"] = 0;
pasta_prices["fettucine"] = 50;
pasta_prices["fusilli"] = 75;

var sauce_prices = new Array();
sauce_prices["pomodoro"] = 0;
sauce_prices["bolognese"] = 50;
sauce_prices["alfredo"] = 100;

function getPastaPrice() {
 var pastaPrice = 0;

 var form = document.forms["myForm"];

 var selectedPasta = myForm.elements["pastatype"];

 for (var i = 0; i < selectedPasta.length; i++) {

  if (selectedPasta[i].checked) {
   pastaPrice = pasta_prices[selectedPasta[i].value];
   break;
  }
 }
 return pastaPrice;
}


function getSaucePrice() {
 var saucePrice = 0;

 var myForm = document.forms["myForm"];

 var selectedSauce = myForm.elements["sauce"];

 saucePrice = sauce_prices[selectedSauce.value];

 return saucePrice;
}

function extrasPrice() {
 var extraPrice = 0;

 var myForm = document.forms["myForm"];

 var includeSalad = myForm.elements["salad"];
 var includeSticks = myForm.elements["sticks"];

 if (includeSalad.checked == true) {
  extraPrice = 200;
 }

 if (includeSticks.checked == true) {

  extraPrice = 100;

 }

 return extraPrice;
}

function calculateOrder() {
 var ordCost = cost + getPastaPrice() + getSaucePrice() + extrasPrice();

 console.log((ordCost / 100).toFixed(2));

 return ordCost;

}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Costello Improved">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Costellos Pasta and Pizza</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="costello.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <style>
    .col-md-12{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    background-color: red;
}

.msg{
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: red;
}

.row{
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    background-color: silver;
    padding: 10px;
}

.label{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#submitMessage{
    transition: opacity 10s;
}

#cancel{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
  </style>
  
</head>

<body>

<form  name="myForm" action="https://costello-pasta.glitch.me/order" id="myForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return calculateOrder()">
      <div class="container">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="debug">Costello's Online Orders</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div   class="col-md-4  label">Pasta Bowl</div>
          <div class="col-md-4"  > (basic price: $7.50)</div>
          <div class="col-md-4"  ></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div   class="col-md-4  label">Pasta</div>
          <div class="col-md-4" >
            <div><input type="radio" name="pastatype" value="0" id="spaghetti"/>Spaghetti (no extra cost)</div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="pastatype" value="50" id="fettucine"/>Fettucine (add 50 cents)</div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="pastatype" value="75" id="fusilli"/>Fusilli (add 75 cents)</div>
            </div>
          <div  class="col-md-4 msg" id="radioLabel"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div   class="col-md-4  label">Sauce</div>
          <div class="col-md-4" >
            <select name="sauce" >
            <option value="0" id="pomodoro">Pomodoro (no extra cost)</option>
            <option value="50" id="bolognese">Bolognese (add 50 cents)</option>
            <option value="100" id="alfredo">Alfredo (add $1.00)</option>
            </select>
            </div>
          <div class="col-md-4" ></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div   class="col-md-4  label">Extras</div>
          <div class="col-md-4" >
             <div><input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="200" id="salad"/>Side salad (add $2.00)</div>
             <div><input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="100" id="sticks"/>Bread sticks (add $1.00)</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4" ></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div   class="col-md-4  label">Name</div>
          <div class="col-md-4" ><input type="text" id="name" name="client_name" /></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 msg"  id="nameLabel"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div   class="col-md-4  label">Phone</div>
          <div class="col-md-4" ><input type="text" id="phone" value="" /></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 msg"  id="phoneLabel"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div   class="col-md-4  label"><input type="submit" value="Order"   /></div>
          <div class="col-md-4"  id="totalcost"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 msg"  id="submitMessage"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your basic snippet seems to work, can you explain how to reproduce the error?

Comment: @CertainPerformance view this https://jsbin.com/qomeroyale/edit?html,js,console,output The console is where I'm seeing the error. The form submits automatically but I need to display the price first before going to the confirmation window.

Comment: @canijusttravel -- the price is getting displayed now in my below jsBin solution but you won't see that in console log because, just after you submit the form, you navigate to other window. If you keep a break point on console.log line, you will see the value in console as well during debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selectedPasta[i].value will give you "0" or "50" accordingly. And they are not present in pastaPrices, hence the return value from getPastaPrice is undefined. Let me modify your jsBin and share the results.

Working JSBin here: https://jsbin.com/qokaboj/edit?html,js,console,output

Here is your working JS code:

```
enter code here

function getPastaPrice(){
  var pastaPrice=0;

  var form = document.forms["myForm"];

  var selectedPasta = myForm.elements["pastatype"];

  for(var i = 0; i < selectedPasta.length; i++) {
    if(selectedPasta[i].checked) {
        pastaPrice = pasta_prices[selectedPasta[i].id];
        break;
    }
  }
  return pastaPrice;
}


function getSaucePrice() {
var saucePrice=0;
var myForm = document.forms["myForm"];

var selectedSauce = myForm.elements["sauce"];
for(var i=0; i<selectedSauce.length; i++){
    if(selectedSauce[i].selected){
        saucePrice = sauce_prices[selectedSauce[i].id];
        break;
    }
}
   return saucePrice;
}

function extrasPrice() {
   var extraPrice=0;
   var myForm = document.forms["myForm"];
   var includeSalad = myForm.elements["salad"];
   var includeSticks = myForm.elements["sticks"];

    if(includeSalad.checked) {
       extraPrice = 200;
    }

    if (includeSticks.checked) {
     extraPrice += 100;
    }
    return extraPrice;
}

function calculateOrder() {
  var ordCost = cost + getPastaPrice() + getSaucePrice() + extrasPrice();

    console.log((ordCost/100).toFixed(2));
    return calculateOrder;
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

the `calculateOrder` function is attempting to return itself:

```
function calculateOrder() {
    [...]
    return calculateOrder;
}
```

Comment: Definitely a problem, but do you know where the ReferenceError OP is describing is coming from?

Comment: This seems more like a comment. There isn't enough information in the question to really answer it though. It's conceivable, although weird that such a function would return itself

Comment: My apologies I made an update to return ordCost not calculateOrder. Must have copied before fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

You created a function called `calculateOrder`

```
function calculateOrder() {
    var ordCost = cost + getPastaPrice() + getSaucePrice() + extrasPrice();

    console.log((ordCost / 100).toFixed(2));

    return calculateOrder; // <--- problem here.

}
```

Instead of returning `calculateOreder` you should return `ordCost`.

How will this help? Well we can do some checks in your function to see that calculateOrder is...not defined! The `calculateOrder` that is not defined is that undefined variable I noted up there.

Go ahead a try this in your code too to see what is and is not defined in your function

```
function calculateOrder() {
    var ordCost = cost + getPastaPrice() + getSaucePrice() + extrasPrice();

    console.log((ordCost / 100).toFixed(2));
    console.log('calculateOrder: ', calculateOrder);
    console.log('ordCost', ordCost)
    return ordCost; //<--- the value you might be looking for

}
```

Comment: Added this and then returned NaN instead of the calculation. Error message I get.                          
"NaN"
"calculateOrder: "
function calculateOrder() {
  var ordCost = cost + getPastaPrice() + getSaucePrice() + extrasPrice();

  window.runnerWindow.proxyConsole.log((ordCost/100).toFixed(2));
  window.runnerWindow.proxyConsole.log('calculateOrder: ', calculateOrder);
  window.runnerWindow.proxyConsole.log('ordCost', ordCost)
  return ordCost;

}
"ordCost"
NaN